# Changing default shell to bash on Sonoma

Tags: terminal, bash, macos

As all the instructions that I can find say, I changed the default shell by doing this command in terminal:

`chsh -s /bin/bash`

I now get this error:

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

Even though I am indeed running bash:

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Comment: That’s not an error.  That’s an informational message. Continue using Bash as you normally would

Comment: @allan Do you know what is generating that message? Because the fact that it says "The default interactive shell is now zsh." worries me that there's a partial config problem somewhere

Comment: macOS uses zhs as the default shell, and has done so [since Catalina](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050). There's no configuration error, partial or otherwise.

Comment: Do you know where that message is generated?

Comment: I can only guess that the `csch` command generates the informational message, and was coded to do so after zsh was made the default shell.

Comment: Do you get the message every time you open a shell/terminal or just when you change it?

Comment: Here's a thought... actually READ the message, which tells you where to get more information, including how to disable the message.  The message is being output by `/bin/bash`.

Comment: 1) It was not in the message; 2) Thanks for the tip about SHELL; 3) Thanks for showing me the existing so post. Very helpful. Happy to close it.